# Question about proof of Royden's Proposition 4.14

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about the following proof by Royden.

[image]

In particular, I am wondering why there is a strict inequality in

$$\int_A (f-f_N) + \int_A f_N < \int_E (f-f_N) + NmA$$

Shouldn't it be $\leq$ because:

Since $f_N\leq N$, I know $\int_A f_N $ $\leq$ $NmA$. Also, since $A\subset  E$, I also know $\int_A (f-f_N)$ $\leq$ $\int_E (f-f_N)$.

Where does the strict inequality come from?

Comment: What is $m$? Presumably it is defined else where in the book?

Comment: @Dom m is lebesgue measure

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that over $A$ (or almost everywhere on $A$) you have $f_N=N$. Just take $N'=N+1$ and use this instead, then you have $f_{N'}\ge f_N$ on $A$ (by definition of $f_m$) and $N'>f_{N'}$ (almost) everywhere on $A$. This will then give you $N'mA>\int_Af_{N'}$.